# java - end session after inactivity for 20s

Tags: java, timer, session-timeout

everyone.

I'm implementing a kind of like custom timer-based session.  It's a singleton class that have start(), pause(), resume() and stop().  What I want to achieve is to have a session timeout.  Say, if pause() is called and after 20 seconds resume() isn't called, I want to call stop() to end that session.

Any ideas how to implement this?

Thanks.

EDITED:

Not really a timer, it's more like a stopwatch timer like this:

```
public class MyTimer{
    private long startTime;
    private long endTime;

    public MyTimer getInstance(){//singleton}

    public void start(){//}
    public void stop(){//}
    public void resume(){//}
    public void pause(){//}
}
```

Singleton

Comment: Use a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)?

Comment: Usually `ScheduledExecutorService` will be the better option, but @Eng.Fouad is right.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a timer for every thread that you want to time out, or:

- Let every thread have it's own timeout counter
- On a seperate thread, regularily (via a timer) iterate your threads and look for the number of seconds since the last timer-resetting action
- stop() the thread whenever the time for the thread has run out, otherwise increase the number of seconds

Still, stop()-ping a thread can lead to all kinds of problems. Better is to check a signal regularily and set the signal to "should be stopped" and let the thread terminate itself.

Comment: Hi, there's only one instance of my class, since I'm using singleton.  And it's not running on a thread.